# Ubuntu 16.04 Brightness & Lock - Screen does not turn off

Tags: 16.04, screen, lock-screen

I have 16.04 LTS on a Dell XPS13 (L321X) and an external LG display connected.

I set it up to:
-dim the screen
-turn screen off when inactive for 10 minutes
-lock ON
-lock screen as soon as screen turns off
-require password when waking from suspend

Problem is that after 10 minutes, both displays get turned off but right after come back on showing the lockscreen. They don't stay off.

This is a fresh 16.04 install.

With my previous installed version, 12.04, this did not happen.

Any known bugs that I may be hitting?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Fortunately, my  [LG 27UK650_600](http://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/27UK650-W%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf) is staying off, but the login screen is burning a hole in my Laptop monitor.

Answer (score 4):

I found out there was a bug related to this unexpected behavior. Bug #1292041.

This got fixed recently with the release of a Unity patch.
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1292041

After updating the OS, it now works well on my setup, the monitors blank off, and stay that way until I hit a key or move the mouse.

Comment: Probably right. I am the one who posted the question AND the answer in first place. I found out that there WAS a bug I was hitting, should've mentioned in the answer. Will edit.

Comment: Links to bug reports aren't considered answers on AU (see also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.). But I see you added the instructions that led to a solution. +1

Comment: This isn't fixed anymore in 16.04.4. Login screen wakes up monitor and stays on.

Comment: This isn't fixed in Ubuntu 16.04.5 either. After the screen goes off, screen lock wakes it back up and it stays on forever.

Comment: This is a problem in 19.04 still (or again).